# Symfony3 and Doctrine DataFixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I have a weird issue with my PhpUnit tests.
I use Symfony3, Doctrine and DataFixtures implements OrderdFixutreInterface.
When I use annotation @ORM/Column in Entity I want to load in DataFixtures, it ends with

```
THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Definition I have in Entity looks like:

```
/**
 * @var SlotPosition
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slot_position_id", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SlotBundle\Entity\SlotPosition")
 */
private $slotPosition;
```

If I remove @ORM\Column part all work good. 
Can someone told me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it might be a conflict with the @JoinColumn you didn't precised.
@JoinColumn is optionnal but if you don't precise it in this case I think doctrine will consider `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="slotPosition_id", referencedColumnName="id")`. I'm not an expert so I don't get why it works when you remove @Column but it might come from there.

```
/**
 * @var SlotPosition
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SlotBundle\Entity\SlotPosition")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="slot_position_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $slotPosition;
```

note: Nullable is by default FALSE for @Column. You can precise it the same way in @JoinColumn as you did in @Column

Comment: It works nice, thank you :) Btw according to this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn  \@JoinColumns has nullable default TRUE but \@Column has nullable defautl FALSE.. Bit messy i think..

Comment: you're right according to the documentation 'nullable' is by default TRUE for `JoinColumn` but it's by default FALSE for `Column` (I actually never noticed that)